# How do I access a nested object in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to loop the nested assignee object in my Angular template. 1st code block is the JSON snippet of the nested object(assignee). 2nd code block is the template of my Angular workspace where I want to display the nested object assignee.

```json
{
        "ticket": 12,
        "title": "Ticket#2",
        "description": "Ticket#2",
        "severity": "Normal",
        "status": "New",
        "assignee": {
            "id": 26,
            "employeeNumber": 101,
            "firstName": "Amy",
            "middleName": "Devie",
            "lastName": "Iliya",
            "department": "HR"
        },
        "watchers": [],
        "empNum": null
    },
```

```html
    <p *ngFor="let ticket of tickets">
      {{ ticket.assignee }}
    </p>
```

The result of this is when I run it is always [object Object]. Also, how I access only the Id in the assignee object?

Comment: use `ticket.assignee.employeeNumber`, `ticket.assignee.id`

Comment: It's always [object Object] because `ticket.assignee` is an object. If you want to access the object's properties you have to specify the key's name, like Nitheesh has suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access nested objects withe the following syntax.

```html
<p *ngFor="let ticket of tickets">
   Name: {{ ticket.assignee.firstName }}
   <br />
   Department: {{ ticket.assignee.department }}
</p>
```

Comment: No description?

Comment: if I have data like a ticket.assignee.department.classroom.bench.student will that work in autoSelect functionality in HTML? Up to how many levels this hierarchy works? Because in my case it is not working with 5 nested levels. Any suggestion?